# question about rewind() function for files in C language

Tags: c, data-structures

I found in a site this explanation :

> The function moves the file position indicator to the beginning of the specified stream, while also clearing the error and EOF flags associated with that stream.

The part that confuse me is: if the rewind function position the pointer to point to the beginning of file, dosen't that automatically remove the "problem".

For example if we were using `fgetc()` and after we used rewind, and `feof(file* stream)` will `return 0` , so we are good to go, wright ?.

Sorry am just trying to say why isn't "moving the file position indicator to the beginning of the specified stream" enough ? do we have to mention "while also clearing the error and EOF flags associated with that stream"
.

Comment: _do we have to mention "while also clearing the error and EOF flags associated with that stream"_ Yes we do, because that's what the function does.  Once set, these flags remain set until explicitly cleared (or cleared as a side-effect of calling some other function on the file).

Comment: The file position and the error flags in this case are conceptually two seperate values. So whilst it is reasonable for you to think that perhaps setting one will automatically affect the other it does not have to be the case. That's why explicitly specifying that behaviour is needed to make that clear.

Comment: So what kind of problem will we have if the function didn't clear the flags ? thank you all .

Comment: Am sorry but i don't really understand Flags.

Comment: If the flags aren't cleared then programs may not work properly. For example, any code that checks `feof` would incorrectly get a true.

Comment: @kaylum thank you that's really helpfull, sorry one last question, i read that fseek does not clear flags, so should i stay away from it and always use rewind ? thanks again